# How to link a Windows 10 PC to a different windows account?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

I have two PCs:

- A: linked to account WindowsA
- B: linked to account WindowsB

I would like PC B to also be linked to account WindowsA, but I am unable to find how this can be achieved. `Settings -> Accounts` shows me my currently used windows account, but it does not allow me change it.

How can I change the windows account linked to my PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this procedure to switch your primary Microsoft account :

1. Go to PC Settings > Accounts and log into a new temporary local account.
2. This will log you out and then you'll log back in using your local account.
3. Once back in, go to Accounts and select Logging in with a Microsoft account and enter the account that you want to use.
4. After that, you should be logged into the right account.

Comment: Works perfectly. One remark: I was scared by the information about drive encryption. I ignored it and proceeded. My understanding is that the key is either still in my computer, or on the old windows account, which I still have access to. I was not able to export the key to the current disk (feedback loop).

Comment: You should have mentioned that the disk was encrypted. Are the files accessible? If they are, then no harm was done, but you should investigate the problem of not being able to export the key.

Comment: No harm was done, I can access everything because I did not fail to login. I am not sure what will happen if I ever lose my login access (like, if I forget my password). The problem with exporting the key is clear: I could not save the encrypting to the encrypted disk (stupid imho: let me do with the key whatever I want to do: I wanted to upload it to Google Drive or Dropbox, or similar), and I did not want to use any of the other options (save to the Windows Account, or print as PDF).

Comment: You might post this as another question here, if you don't manage to solve it, with more details.